# Error in model.frame.default(formula = GHGpc ~ GDPpc + GDP_SQAURED_PER_CAPITA + : invalid type (list) for variable 'GDP_SQAURED_PER_CAPITA'

Tags: list, linear-regression

HI could i please have some help with this error as I have tried the C and unlist function which are the commonly solved solutions. i have Tried the C and Unlist function to convert the lists to vectors. Any suggestions?, this variable is the only quadratic in the environment.